# React Native: How to import local image with dynamic name

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have about 100 heroes' image on local that need to import into the listview. This is my hero.js

```
renderRow(hero) {
return (
          <View>
              <View style={styles.container}>
                  <Image
                      source={require('./img/hero/'+hero.img+'.jpg')}
                      style={styles.thumbnail} />
                  <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
                      <Text style={styles.title}>{hero.name}</Text>
                  </View>
              </View>
              <View style={styles.separator} />
          </View>
);
```

After some research I know **require** won't allow dynamic name. I also tried uri, no error but no image either.

```
{{uri: './img/hero/'+hero.img+'.jpg'}}
```

My folder structure is like this:

```
Project
  index.ios.js
  hero.js
  img
    hero
```

What is the best way to handle this, I don't want to put images on the network.

Answer (score 0):

sahrens said the following on this [forum](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2481)

> We intentionally don't support dynamically generated image names because it makes it very hard to manage assets over time, just like how you wouldn't want to do

It looks like it can be done via `uri` but it will require a bit of work. You will need to add your images in xcode assets and for android under res/drawable.

Then you can get your image with `<Image source={{ uri: "image" + "name" }} />`

Comment: I see, but manually adding all images into xcode assets folder isn't fun at all :(

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue in one way, just post my answer here in case others interesting on how to deal with this.

I wrote a php script to read all images in my hero folder and print out in this format:

`heroName: require ('./img/hero/heroName.jpg')`

```
<?php
    $dir = "./img/hero";

    // Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
            $images = array();

            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                $keyName = str_replace(".jpg","",$file);
                print "$keyName: require('./img/hero/$file'),". "<br />";
            }

            closedir($dh);

        }
    }
?>
```

Then I copy the result, paste into a js file and store as object like this:

```
export default heroList = {
   name1: require('./img/hero/name1.jpg'),
   name2: require('./img/hero/name2.jpg'),
   etc....
}
```

Finally in my hero.js file:

```
import heroList from './heroList';
....
source={heroList[heroName]}
```